# In pyqt, how to get access the dockwidget on a QDockWidgetArea QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

If I've created a QMainWindow instance, and assign the central widget and dock widgets for it:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, MyCentralWidget, MyDockWidget):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(MyCentralWidget)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea,MyDockWidget)
        self.show()

Instance=MyWindow(A,B)
```

Then I think I can get access to the center widget A by `Instance.centralWidget()`, but how can I get access to the dockwidget in the LeftDockWidgetArea similarly? (for example, I want to modify the properties of the Widget in that dockwidget after instance is created)

Comment: `self.dockWidget = MyDockWidget`.

Comment: If I add this to the __init__(), and update the dockWidget later. Do I have to manually replace or update the LeftDockWIdgetArea of the MainWindow?

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
self.dockWidgetContents.your_widget...
```